# Modifying amount value when the user edit the amount of water

Tags: android, flutter, dart

These are `_deleteItem` and `_editItem` functions I don't know how to add or delete the amount of water that was modified by the user in Your Drink Goal part. I want when the user edits the amount of water in Today's records to show the change in Your Drink Goal part. [image: see here]

```
void _deleteItem(int index, String unit) {
    final userDataProvider =
        Provider.of<UserDataProvider>(context, listen: false);
    setState(() {
      userDataProvider.items.value.removeAt(index);
      unit == 'kilograms'
          ? userDataProvider.amount -= 175
          : userDataProvider.amount -= 6;
    });
    setData();
  }

  void _editItem(int index) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        final userDataProvider =
            Provider.of<UserDataProvider>(context, listen: false);
        String updatedTime = userDataProvider.items.value[index].time;
        String updatedAmount =
            userDataProvider.items.value[index].amountOfWater;
        TextEditingController timeController =
            TextEditingController(text: updatedTime);
        TextEditingController amountController =
            TextEditingController(text: updatedAmount);
        return Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
              return Container(
                height: 300,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Edit Record',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 7, 107, 132),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Time',
                        hintText: 'Enter new time',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          updatedTime = value;
                          userDataProvider.items.value[index].time = value;
                        });
                      },
                      controller: timeController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Amount of Water',
                        hintText: 'Enter new amount',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          updatedAmount = value;
                          userDataProvider.items.value[index].amountOfWater =
                              value;
                          // userDataProvider.amount += int.parse(value);
                          print(value);
                        });
                      },
                      controller: amountController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
                        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 7, 107, 132),
                      ),
                      child: const Text('Save'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        userDataProvider.items.notifyListeners();
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        setData();
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I provid the link of my project in GitHub [text](https://github.com/ftoome545/Water-Reminder-app)

I try to add this

```
widget.unit == 'kilograms'
? userDataProvider.amount += 
userDataProvider.items.value[index].amountOfWater as double
: userDataModel.amount += 
userDataProvider.items.value[index].amountOfWater as double;
```

but this doesn't work with me.

Comment: Use `double.parse(userDataProvider.items.value[index].amountOfWater)` to parse String to double